# How to fInd the index from which distance of every requirements are closest to the Index

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
let blocks = [
  {
    gym:false,
    school:true,
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:true,
    school:false,
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:true,// and this contains gym
    school:true,
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:false,
    school:true,  // this block is the answer as I can find all three requirements near to this index above and below index; 
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:false,
    school:true, // this contains store
    store:true,
  }
]

let filter = ['school','gym','store'];
```

Eg. Here the correct index is 3 as 2,3,4 index fulfilled all the requirements element. We could have n number of requirements and n number of elements.

Comment: Please define "distance to every requirement" more precisely. Even if there is a natural "smallest distance to an element which has a required value" (which I believe you are referring to), how do you aggregate them? Sum them? Average them? Something else?

Comment: Since you tagged this [dynamic-programming], it seems you already have chosen an approach. Can you show us your attempt at the code, please, and ask a specific question about the part that you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

Not sure what you want to do if the filter array has 4 items? If you then find the items you want at indexes 1, 2, 3, 4 - do you return index 2 or 3 or 2.5, for example?

Also, if you have your filter array as it currently is but you find two of the items at index 2 and the other at index 3 - do you return 2 or 3 or 2.5? (see second code snippet)

For now, I just return the dictionary and you can decide how to return your index.

```js
let blocks = [
  {
    gym:false,
    school:true,
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:true,
    school:false,
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:true,// and this contains gym
    school:true,
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:false,
    school:true,  // this block is the answer as I can find all three requirements near to this index above and below index; 
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:false,
    school:true, // this contains store
    store:true,
  }
]

let filter = ['school','gym','store'];

function findIndex(blocks, filter) {
  const filterLen = filter.length;
  const trackingObj = filter.reduce((agg,obj) => {
    agg[obj] = [];
    return agg;
  }, {});
  let foundIdx = null;
  outerLoop: for (let idx in blocks) {
    const obj = blocks[idx];
    for (let key in trackingObj) {
      const val = trackingObj[key];
      // reset the obj key if any idx are "too far away"
      if (val.length > 0) {
        trackingObj[key] = val.filter(v => v > (idx - filterLen));
      }
    }
    for (let key of filter) {
      if (obj[key] == true) {
        // save the index into the obj
        trackingObj[key].push(parseInt(idx));
      }
    }
    for (let key in trackingObj) {
      const val = trackingObj[key];
      if (val.length == 0) {
        continue outerLoop;
      }
    }
    // will only reach if all keys of trackingObj are not empty:
    foundIdx = idx; // not sure what index you expect to return
    break;
  }
  // return foundInd; // not sure what index you expect to return
  return trackingObj;
}

console.log(findIndex(blocks, filter));
```

returns:

```js
{
  "school": [2, 3, 4],
  "gym": [2],
  "store": [4]
}
```

Here is another example to show what I meant earlier:

```js
let blocks = [
  {
    gym:false,
    school:false,
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:false,
    school:false,
    store:false,
  },
  {
    gym:true,// this contains gym
    school:true, // and school
    store:false,
  },
  // do I return 2 or 3 or 2.5?
  {
    gym:false,
    school:true,  // this contains school
    store:true, // and store
  },
  {
    gym:false,
    school:true,
    store:true,
  }
]

let filter = ['school','gym','store'];

function findIndex(blocks, filter) {
  const filterLen = filter.length;
  const trackingObj = filter.reduce((agg,obj) => {
    agg[obj] = [];
    return agg;
  }, {});
  let foundIdx = null;
  outerLoop: for (let idx in blocks) {
    const obj = blocks[idx];
    for (let key in trackingObj) {
      const val = trackingObj[key];
      // reset the obj key if any idx are "too far away"
      if (val.length > 0) {
        trackingObj[key] = val.filter(v => v > (idx - filterLen));
      }
    }
    for (let key of filter) {
      if (obj[key] == true) {
        // save the index into the obj
        trackingObj[key].push(parseInt(idx));
      }
    }
    for (let key in trackingObj) {
      const val = trackingObj[key];
      if (val.length == 0) {
        continue outerLoop;
      }
    }
    // will only reach if all keys of trackingObj are not empty:
    foundIdx = idx; // not sure what index you expect to return
    break;
  }
  // return foundInd; // not sure what index you expect to return
  return trackingObj;
}

console.log(findIndex(blocks, filter));
```

returns this and I am not sure if the return idx should be 2, 2.5 or 3?:

```js
{
  "school": [2, 3],
  "gym": [2],
  "store": [3]
}
```